# Не могу открыть ссылку с созданием нового поста

Tags: wordpress

При нажатии на создание нового поста появляется такое окно (Хром)
В FireFox я могу открыть страницу создания поста, но после создания поста, ссылка на новый пост становится такой же как и предыдущий пост, поэтому создается новый пост поверх старого.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> после создания поста, ссылка на новый пост становится такой же как и
>   предыдущий пост, поэтому создается новый пост поверх старого.

Такое наблюдается, если сервер отдаёт заголовок `Pragma`

Можно добавить  в functions.php активной темы:

```
function add_pragma_no_cache_header( $headers ) {
    $headers['Pragma'] = 'no-cache';
    return $headers;
}
add_filter( 'nocache_headers', 'add_pragma_no_cache_header' );
```

См. https://ru.wordpress.org/support/topic/%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%83%d1%8e%d1%89%d0%b8%d1%85/#post-244839